# WP8 - SkyDrive API Uploading files error

Tags: windows-phone-8, onedrive

Basically I'm having this problem. So I've created a folder in skydrive from my app and I want to upload a textfile to that folder but it simply isn't letting me. Bascailly the only way i can upload the textfile is if i set the location to "me/skydrive". I wan't it so that the textfile gets uploaded to a folder on SkyDrive called "Pencil Notes".

My code soo far is:

```
 Dim myIsolatedStorage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim mp1 = TryCast(App.RootFrame.Content, MainMenu)
    Dim dataSource As New List(Of SampleData1)()
    Dim data = TryCast(ItemsListSkyDrive.SelectedItem, SampleData1)

    Dim writeFile As New StreamWriter(New IsolatedStorageFileStream("/shared/transfers/" & data.Name & ".txt", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
    Dim Title As String = data.Name
    Dim Message As String = data.Description
    writeFile.WriteLine(Title)
    writeFile.WriteLine(Message)
    writeFile.Close()

    Dim store1 As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Using store As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
        Try
            Dim res As LiveOperationResult = Await client.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive/Pencil Notes", New Uri("/shared/transfers/" & data.Name & ".txt", UriKind.Relative), OverwriteOption.Overwrite)
            MessageBox.Show("Done", "", MessageBoxButton.OK)
            store1.DeleteFile("/shared/transfers/" & data.Name & ".txt")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButton.OK)
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: I posted a answer it would help you ....actually i provide the code in c# but you could use in your code

Answer (score 0):

This PostCompleted event is use to upload your files in skydrive:

```
client.PostCompleted +=
                        new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(CreateMyFolder_Completed);
 void CreateMyFolder_Completed(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
               string folderID = (e.Result["id"]).ToString();
                foreach (string item in names)
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        string filename = item;
                        if (store.FileExists(filename))
                        {
                            IsolatedStorageFileStream storeStream = store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                            client.UploadAsync(folderID, filename, storeStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);

                        }                         
                    }
                }
            }
```

This would help you

Comment: Thanks for that but i didn't work :( There wasn't no LiveOperationCompleted Event. Any other way?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Live SDK. All i need to do is make sure that the file gets uploaded to the created folder. Nothing else. It's quite odd though how it can be uploaded to the SkyDrive folder but not any subfolders.

Comment: where you asked about uploading file into subfolder in your query?

Comment: well i assumed you got the idea? if not sorry about that.

Comment: if  i am not wrong , there you are asking for folder, Please make sure before posting any query

Comment: I'l make sure next time, are you able to find an alternative way?

Comment: would try .....but as i knew this api it's providing to create folder....ok we would try for solution

Comment: Yea It does provide you to create a folder and I've done so there sin't a problem there. It's just that I don't get why it's soo tricky to just upload the folder inside another folder...